# How to dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I am trying to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18.04. I just installed Windows 7 64 bit so it is a fresh install. I added a partition for Ubuntu in Windows disk management and then installed Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB using "something else".
I used [these instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOfnvbdWhrs) to install.

I made the partitions in Windows. After booting from USB and creating more partitions in "something else" and clicking on install it gave me an error:

> Partition table requires a separate partition for boot loader code.

I installed anyway.

When the install was done it had to restart. But it booted back into Windows, no GRUB. I restarted window and still no GRUB.

So I try to install again and I chose to reinstall over Ubuntu. Same thing. No GRUB.

I am running a

```
I5-2500
8gb DDR 3 ram
gigabyte motherboard
1tb hard drive with Windows 10 unplugged this whole time
500gb hard drive For windows 7 and Ubuntu 
Windows 7 says EFI boot mode
```

I have tried to do (`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`).
It says completed successfully. But no diffrance when I restart.

Comment: Fixed the spelling. I am dyslexic so that is why.

Answer (score 0):

By default GRUB is set disabled in most systems, you can set it enable while your system is booting by clicking escape button. Already check it? Check if whole installation is correct; means if installation is complete? You might be missing some step in installation.

If you are in desperate need of Ubuntu, you can try Oracle virtual box or VMWare. It's very easy to install in Windows, and they are sandboxed; it means whatever happens inside it will not affect your global system, here windows. It will provide all the functionalities you'll be needing in dual boot. Its easy and more safe, and practically it is recommended. If you want to know exact procedure, visit online or comment it.

Comment: Ok. I got to the grub and can get into Ubuntu. How do I set it to desply grub every time? Also windows was not a option in the grub. How do I get that?

Comment: If you enable the grub, it should give option for each time for booting Ubuntu or Windows.